# WCF service refactoring

Tags: performance, wcf

In my project the developers developed a WCF service which has 500+ methods so when I did small changes in the service side it takes lot of time to update the service in client application.

Is there any alternative way to improve the performance in the client side for updating the service.

Comment: Read up on the [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and also give that link to those service developers of yours.....

Comment: Thanks for the link @marc

Comment: Are all operations in a same interface/class? You can group the operations by business subject, so you can have some different classes/interfaces, and when you need to make changes, you can deploy only updated code.

Comment: All operations are written in one interface only...

Comment: Hi @marc_s as per ur suggestion i implemented the interface but it is taking the same time to debug the service..............